# Got error using Twitter Search in PHP

Tags: php, twitter

While searching on Twitter using PHP after searching 2 or 3 I got error of you have been rate limited.enhance your calm in PHP

```
 function twitter_class()
{
    $this->realNamePattern = '/\((.*?)\)/';


$this->intervalNames   = array('second', 'minute', 'hour', 'day', 'week', 'month', 'year');
$this->intervalSeconds = array( 1,        60,       3600,   86400, 604800, 2630880, 31570560);

    $this->badWords = array('somebadword', 'anotherbadword');
}
function searchURL($language, $query) {
    $func_args=func_get_args();
    $vars = array_map('urlencode', $func_args + array('', ''));        
    return vsprintf('http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang=%s&q=%s', $vars);
}

function getTweets($q,$lang, $limit=15)
{
    $output = '';

    // get the seach result

   $ch = curl_init($this->searchURL($lang, $q));


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($response !== FALSE)
    {
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);

        $output = '';
        $tweets = 0;

        for($i=0; $i<count($xml->entry); $i++)
        {
            $crtEntry = $xml->entry[$i];
            $account  = $crtEntry->author->uri;
            $image    = $crtEntry->link[1]->attributes()->href;
            $tweet    = $crtEntry->content;

            // skip tweets containing banned words
            $foundBadWord = false;
            foreach ($this->badWords as $badWord)
            {
                if(stristr($tweet, $badWord) !== FALSE)
                {
                    $foundBadWord = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            $tweet = str_replace('<a href=', '<a target="_blank" href=', $tweet);

            // skip this tweet containing a banned word
            if ($foundBadWord)
                continue;

            // don't process any more tweets if at the limit
            if ($tweets==$limit)
                break;
            $tweets++;

            // name is in this format "acountname (Real Name)"
            preg_match($this->realNamePattern, $crtEntry->author->name, $matches);
            $name = $matches[1];

            // get the time passed between now and the time of tweet, don't allow for negative
            // (future) values that may have occured if server time is wrong
            $time = 'just now';
            $secondsPassed = time() - strtotime($crtEntry->published);

            if ($secondsPassed>0)
            {
                // see what interval are we in
                for($j = count($this->intervalSeconds)-1; ($j >= 0); $j--)
                {
                    $crtIntervalName = $this->intervalNames[$j];
                    $crtInterval = $this->intervalSeconds[$j];

                    if ($secondsPassed >= $crtInterval)
                    {
                        $value = floor($secondsPassed / $crtInterval);
                        if ($value > 1)
                            $crtIntervalName .= 's';

                        $time = $value . ' ' . $crtIntervalName . ' ago';

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here is my code please have a look on it and find exact solution what i am laging

Answer (score 1):

There is aret limit on using Twitter API. 
If you are testing that code on a shared server (means if your ip is using by other people whom using twitter API) that can cause this.
Or you are making too much requests...

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting#search

> Search API Rate Limiting
>
> Requests to the Search API, hosted on search.twitter.com, do not count
>   towards the REST API limit. However, all requests coming from an IP
>   address are applied to a Search Rate Limit. The Search Rate Limit
>   isn't made public to discourage unnecessary search usage and abuse,
>   but it is higher than the REST Rate Limit. We feel the Search Rate
>   Limit is both liberal and sufficient for most applications and know
>   that many application vendors have found it suitable for their needs.
>
> Requirements for the Search API
>
> Search API usage requires that applications include a unique and
>   identifying User Agent string. An HTTP Referrer is expected but is not
>   required. Applications using the Search API but failing to include a
>   User Agent string will receive a lower rate limit.
>
> An application that exceeds the rate limitations of the Search API
>   will receive an HTTP 420 response code. It is best practice to watch
>   for this error condition and honor the Retry-After header which is
>   returned. The Retry-After header's value is the number of seconds your
>   application should wait before requesting date from the Search API
>   again.
>
> Use Streaming APIs Instead
>
> The Search API is best suited for user-initiated ad-hoc queries. If
>   your application requires repeated Search API polling, you might want
>   to consider the Streaming API instead.
>
> Tips to avoid being Rate Limited
>
> The tips below are there to help you code defensively and reduce the
>   possibility of being rate limited.
>
> Some application features that you may want to provide are simply
>   impossible in light of rate limiting, especially around the freshness
>   of results. If real-time information is an aim of your application,
>   look into User Streams or Site Streams.
>
> Caching
>
> Store API responses in your application or on your site if you expect
>   a lot of use. For example, don't try to call the Twitter API on every
>   page load of your website landing page. Instead, call the API
>   infrequently and load the response into a local cache. When users hit
>   your website load the cached version of the results.
>
> Prioritize active users
>
> If your site keeps track of many Twitter users (for example, fetching
>   their current status or statistics about their Twitter usage),
>   consider only requesting data for users who have recently signed into
>   your site.
>
> Adapt to the search results
>
> If your application monitors a high volume of search terms, query less
>   often for searches that have no results than for those that do. By
>   using a back-off you can keep up to date on queries that are popular
>   but not waste cycles requesting queries that very rarely change.
>
> Alternatively, consider using the Streaming API and filter on your
>   search terms.

Comment: How can we avoid to not be limit by Twitter is there any PHP code for it?

Comment: You can't, you just need to make less requests. As documantation says best practice is not to make another call before "Retry-After" seconds passed.  `It is best practice to watch for this error condition and honor the Retry-After header which is returned. The Retry-After header's value is the number of seconds your application should wait before requesting date from the Search API again.`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bypass twitter limit, then you either get lots of machines with different IP's and distribute search requests among them so that they are called at different times, or move the query to the client side (assuming you have lots of clients looking) and hope that they improve your bandwidth, though it will not be as secure.